# error while creating apache beam dataflow job and inserting into bigquery

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, streaming, apache-beam

I am reading the list of jobs from the google API "ml.googleapis.com" and then creating a topic using pub/sub. And when I trying to read the message from the topic and write into bigquery table I am getting an error "No fields named field.638".

I am converting the output from "ml.googleapis.com" into a pandas dataframe and then convert it to a dict and then write into bigquery table. This might be the problem. Any help here is really appreciated. Please find the python code below I used to test. Thanks.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# you use one auth
client = Clients.get_client(ClientType.AUTO_ML_API, name='abc')
client1 = Clients.get_client(ClientType.BIGQUERY, name='abc')

from datetime import datetime
for  Index,row in df1.iterrows():
    jobs = execute_command(client.projects().jobs(), 'list', parent='projects/'+row['project'],fetch_field ='jobs',filter=f"createTime.seconds>={filterseconds}")
    df = pd.DataFrame(jobs, columns = ['jobId', 'trainingInput', 'createTime', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'state', 'trainingOutput', 'etag', 'labels', 'errorMessage'])
    df = df.astype('str')
    if len(df) > 0:
            project = row['project']
            df['project'] = project
            df1 = df.to_dict()
            err1 = client1.insert_rows_json(table,[df1])
            print(err1)
```

json is

original_json =

```
{  "jobId": "clid_167_training_demo_train_2022_03_23_14_43_39",  "trainingInput": "{\u0027scaleTier\u0027: \u0027CUSTOM\u0027, \u0027masterType\u0027: \u0027n1-standard-8\u0027, \u0027packageUris\u0027: [\u0027gs://xyz/clid_167_training_demo_train_2022_03_23_14_43_39/bc2cff80468ca3acf9d94c67292594ae25204bd436833f8a0cac76f6202c30e9/vie-model-training-pipeline-0.1.1.tar.gz\u0027], \u0027pythonModule\u0027: \u0027vie_model_training_pipeline.main\u0027, \u0027region\u0027: \u0027us-central1\u0027, \u0027runtimeVersion\u0027: \u00272.5\u0027, \u0027pythonVersion\u0027: \u00273.7\u0027, \u0027masterConfig\u0027: {\u0027acceleratorConfig\u0027: {\u0027count\u0027: \u00271\u0027, \u0027type\u0027: \u0027N_P100\u0027}}}",  "createTime": "2022-03-23T14:43:41Z",  "startTime": "2022-03-23T14:47:58Z",  "endTime": "2022-03-23T14:53:00Z",  "state": "FAILED",  "trainingOutput": "{\u0027consumedMLUnits\u0027: 0.63}",  "etag": "/f6SGm5N6a8\u003d",  "labels": "nan",  "errorMessage": "The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. \nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  [...]\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code\n    exec(code, run_globals)\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vie_model_training_pipeline/main.py\", line 115, in \u003cmodule\u003e\n    main()\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vie_model_training_pipeline/main.py\", line 96, in main\n    log_dir\u003dModelSettings.log_dir,\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vie_model_training_pipeline/train.py\", line 44, in train\n    callbacks\u003d[reduce_lr, modelcheck, tensorboard, csv_logger, early_stopping],\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py\", line 1183, in fit\n    tmp_logs \u003d self.train_function(iterator)\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py\", line 889, in __call__\n    result \u003d self._call(*args, **kwds)\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py\", line 950, in _call\n    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py\", line 3024, in __call__\n    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs\u003dgraph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable\u003dprotected-access\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py\", line 1961, in _call_flat\n    ctx, args, cancellation_manager\u003dcancellation_manager))\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py\", line 596, in call\n    ctx\u003dctx)\n  File \"/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py\", line 60, in quick_execute\n    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)\ntensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes at loc(unknown)\n\t [[node Equal (defined at root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vie_model_training_pipeline/train.py:44) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_16218]\n\nFunction call stack:\ntrain_function\n\n\nTo find out more about why your job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/task_training_demo_train_2022_03_23_14_43_39\u0026advancedFilter\u003dresource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%22clid_167_training_demo_train_2022_03_23_14_43_39%22",  "project": "xyz"}
```

Error from the dataflow job is google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project/datasets/junk/tables/tbl/insertAll?prettyPrint=false: Invalid value at 'rows[0].json' . The schema of the table is

```
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("jobId", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE",  fields=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("jobId", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("trainingInput", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("scaleTier", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("masterType", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("packageUris", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE",fields=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("packageUris", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]) ,
        bigquery.SchemaField("pythonModule", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("region", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("runtimeVersion", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("pythonVersion", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("masterConfig", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
                bigquery.SchemaField("acceleratorConfig", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
                        bigquery.SchemaField("count", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
                        bigquery.SchemaField("type", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    ])]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("createTime", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("createTime", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("startTime", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("startTime", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField(
        "endTime",
        "RECORD",
        mode="NULLABLE",
        fields=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("endTime", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        ],
    ),

    bigquery.SchemaField("state", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("state", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("trainingOutput", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("consumedMLUnits", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("etag", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("etag", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("labels", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("labels", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("errorMessage", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("errorMessage", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
    bigquery.SchemaField("project", "RECORD", mode="NULLABLE", fields=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("project", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")]),
]
```

In the dataflow job I am reading the message(dict) from the topic and writing into bigquery as follows:

```
PUBSUB_TOPIC_PROJECT = "xyz"
TOPIC = "q6"
SUBSCRIPTION = "k6"

######################
# Configuration
######################

# Dataflow
DATAFLOW_PIPELINE_VAR = {
    "service_account": "svc",
    "job_name": "job10",
    "streaming": True,
}

def parse(msg):
    from datetime import datetime
    import logging
   
    try:
        logging.info(f'msg is{msg}')
    except ValueError:
        logging.info("Parsed: %s", msg)
    return msg


def MainDataflowJob(p):
    lines = (p | "Read from Pub/Sub topic" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
        subscription=f"projects/{PUBSUB_TOPIC_PROJECT}/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION}")
             | "Parse from JSON" >> beam.Map(parse)
             | "Write to Bigquery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(project=TARGET_PROJECT, dataset=TARGET_DATASET,
                                                              table=TARGET_TABLE))
```

Comment: Are you sure the json you're reading from PubSub never has anything named "field.638?" Perhaps you could do some more validation in your `parse` method (which doesn't seem to be parsing, just passing things on, so maybe it's treating the entire string as a list of characters).

Comment: The json doesn't have a field like "field.638?".  The number "638" is the row value from the dataframe. Looking into parsing the json and removing those row values from the dataframe.